Why are glyphs in new font not aligned to the baseline?
I am experimenting with font generation, first using FontForge and then FontLab 8.  This problem persists in both applications, although I am now not persuaded it is the fault of either.  I have created an OpenType font called newchars.otf that contains a few new glyphs based on TeX Gyre Termes.  Whenever I generate this font from FontForge or a second similar one created entirely in FontLab 8, the new characters are not aligned at the baseline as shown here.

This is generated by the code
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,amsmath}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Consolas}

\newfontfamily\mtcyrillic{newchars.otf}[NFSSFamily=newchars,Script=Math]
\DeclareSymbolFont{nc}{TU}{newchars}{m}{n}

\Umathchardef\dei  = 1 \symnc"003EF
\Umathchardef\Dei  = 1 \symnc"003EE

\begin{document}
    
\[
\mathrm{e}\dei\mathrm{tqT}\Dei\mathrm{I}
\]
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{center}
e$\dei$tqT$\Dei$I   \\
\fbox{$\dei\Dei$}
\end{center}
\end{document}

although without the actual font, I realize this MWE is not reproducible.
Strangely, the lowercase \dei is too high and the uppercase \Dei is too low and, as seen in the box, they appear to be aligned on some centerline.  I have tried this with and without the Script=Math clause: no difference. I have tried fooling with every possible setting in the two applications that I can think of, including editing the BASE table--something you can do with FontForge but not FontLab (?!).  This morning, it occurred to me to see what this looks like in Microsoft Word:

This is correctly aligned, so now I am even more stumped.  The fact that these two new characters are defined as math symbols may explain why they seem center-aligned, which brings me back to the BASE table (I think that math is aligned to a different baseline--a center line--in OpenType than text).  Although I demonstrated that the misalignment occurs in both text and math mode, all that really proves is that TeX Gyre Termes is correctly aligned between the modes and my font is not.  I should mention that I copied all the font settings that I know how to find from TeX Gyre Termes into the new font.
I would be persuaded entirely that this is on the XeTeX end of things (because it is correctly aligned in Word) if it were not for the fact that every other existing font loads just fine as shown above without any misalignment (so why I should I need to do something different for mine on the TeX end?).  There does not appear to be a StackExchange community specifically addressing font design, but since it seems like this could be on the TeX (and offshoots) end, I am hoping someone here knows what is going wrong and how to fix it.

Difficult without the font, but what if you change = 1 to = 0 in your definitions?

@mickep That was it!  Sometimes you cannot see the forest for the trees... Thanks!

Oh, lucky one. I suggest you write an answer that you accept, explaining why. Good luck with the font!

Thanks to @mickep, the answer is to rewrite the \Umathchardef definitions as
\Umathchardef\dei  = 0 \symnc"003EF
\Umathchardef\Dei  = 0 \symnc"003EE

I had previously been working with new integral signs and just blindly copied and pasted.  For those, like me, who often lose track of where we originally found pertinent information, the math <type>s are found, among other places, in fntguide.pdf:

Thank you, again, @mickep!
